# Create a gensim corpus from term-frequency matrix or from a collection of strings

Tags: nlp, gensim, corpus, word2vec

I am trying to use gensim for topic classification. I already have all feature words from multiple documents in the following form:

```
corpus = [['word1','word2',..],['A','B',...]] (python list of lists)
```

and also a term-frequency matrix in sparse form and a dict.

I was trying to train gensim LDA on this:

```
 lda_model = gensim.models.LdaModel(term_freq_matrix, num_topics=10, id2word=feature_names_dict, passes=4)
```

But I get the following error:

```
  File "/home/oliver/Environments/cmpdp/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gensim/models/ldamodel.py", line 523, in <genexpr>
    corpus_words = sum(cnt for document in chunk for _, cnt in document)
ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack
```

From this tutorial http://radimrehurek.com/topic_modeling_tutorial/2%20-%20Topic%20Modeling.html
it seems like it all looks okay, only the sparse matrix form looks a bit different:

My corpus:

```
 print(next(iter(term_freq_matrix)))
  (0, 12036)    1
  (0, 12406)    2
...
  (0, 3916) 1
  (0, 3157) 1
```

Tutorial corpus:
print(next(iter(mm_corpus)))

```
[(24, 1.0), (38, 1.0), (53, 1.0), (103, 1.0), (111, 1.0), (213, 3.0), (237, 1.0), (242, 2.0)]
```

What do you think?